# Set Forecolor in my wpf listview for colum which has value as True

Tags: wpf

here in my WPF application am using listview with 5 columns and one of the column has flag value and my requirement is, if the flag value is True then i have to set the forground of the row to RED color....Thank you

Comment: If you post some XAML and/or code, it can make things alot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use a value converter

**Resources**

- http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/value_converters_pg1.htm
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2010/05/11/customizing-your-wpf-silverlight-ui-using-value-converter-and-or-partial-class-properties.aspx

Or concider MVVM-like patern

- http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/using-a-viewmodel-as-a-value-converter/

Comment: I cant get your code from msdn,beacuse am new to wpf,so could you please give me a clear solution for this nad here is my code – Prabhakaran 1 min ago edit I cant get your code from msdn,beacuse am new to wpf,so could you please give me a clear solution for this nad here is my code 
 <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=IsCompleted}" Width="50" > <GridViewColumnHeader HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">IsCompleted</GridViewColumnHeader> </GridViewColumn> if this value is TRUE i need to get the entire listitem foregrund as RED color

Answer (score 0):

Create a style for the `ListBoxItem` with a `DataTrigger` that changes the color.

In fact, the [MSDN entry on DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) contains an example which is quite close to what you want: It changes the Foreground color to Red based on a data value.

Comment: I cant get your code from msdn,beacuse am new to wpf,so could you please give me a clear solution for this nad here is my code

Comment: <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=IsCompleted}" Width="50" >
                                <GridViewColumnHeader HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">IsCompleted</GridViewColumnHeader>                                
                            </GridViewColumn> if this value is TRUE i need to get the entire listitem foregrund as RED color

Comment: Please show the XAML code of your complete ListView. You can use the "edit" button below your question to add it to your question.